# Product of the digits of an 11-digit number in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a code on multiplicative persistence and I need to write a function which calculates the product of the digits in a number. This is a basic function and I have written it, but I have realized that it can't calculate the product of any number which has more than 10 digits. If the number has 11 or more digits it just says "903168", no matter what number is entered.

This is how it looks like on its own:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a; int product = 1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    do  
    { 
        product = product * (a % 10);
        a = a / 10;
    } 
    while (a != 0);

    cout << "The product of the digits of this number is: " << product;
}
```

Has anyone else faced the same problem? Do you know how can I fix it in order to be able to use this function for any number?

Comment: Your algorithm seems fine, it's just that you can't take in an `int` that has more than 10 digits or so. How about reading the input as a `std::string` and doing the logic on that?

Comment: 2,147,483,647 = 2^31-1 is the largest possible number for 4 byte signed int

Comment: Really? Thank you so much! I will try to do it with strings instead.

Comment: FYI the number of bits (which determines the range of integers which can be expressed) in an C/C++ `int` is implementation-specific to your compiler. You could check if your compiler has a `long int` type that is 64 bits, which is fairly likely these days, but is still implementation-specific. Or you could consider using a different and more abstract language like Python which doesn’t have the same implementation-specific constraints on the range of integer values. Other languages also can offer this benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with time-complexity `O(log n)`. Recursion can reduce time complexity at times. Hope this helps your problem!

```cpp
int getPro(long int n) {
    if (n==0)
        return 1;

    return (n%10)*getPro(n/10);
}
```

Comment: No need of recursion, here. Also, are you sure that the result of `getPro(0)` should be 1?

Comment: Please also note that OP's solution has the same logarithmic time complexity with respect to the magnitude of the inputted number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a larger type to hold your input number and product. On your system, `int` is almost certainly 32 bits. Let's use `long long int` which is 64 bits.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int a; 
    long long int product = 1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    do  
    { 
        product = product * (a % 10);
        a = a / 10;
    } 
    while (a != 0);

    cout << "The product of the digits of this number is: " << product << endl;
}
```

Now:

```
% ./a.out
Enter a number: 12345678912
The product of the digits of this number is: 725760                           % ./a.out     
Enter a number: 99999999999
The product of the digits of this number is: 31381059609
```

Modifying the above code to avoid `using namespace std;` and to use types which make the number of bits more apparent.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;

    int64_t a; 
    int64_t product = 1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    do  
    { 
        product *= a % 10;
        a /= 10;
    } 
    while (a);

    cout << "The product of the digits of this number is: " 
         << product
         << endl;
}
```